# I'm not sure how to model the following data structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble modeling some data. I'm not sure if I should use a polymorphic relationship, multiple models, or denormalize my data.

I want to record "logs" for an exercise. I also want to record "logs" of my meals.

So if I record a set of bench press, I'd record weight/reps. I might also record the macros of my meal, so 300 calories, 5carbs, 5 fat.

Should this be one model called "Log"?

Log => weight/reps/calories/carbs/fat

It may potentially log more than just weights for an exercise. Potential distance is there too, so you could add distance and duration to that model as well.

On top of that, if one was to record their meals, what model should log belong to in relation to a diet?

---

Summary: A user should have the ability to record logs on the exercise they performed, which can include reps, weight, distance, and duration. A user should also have the ability to record their macros throughout the day as they eat. Should there be **one common log model?**

Clarify: A workout is a collection of exercises. An exercise is something like running or bench-press.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would rather them broken apart so the code is highly legible.

**Meal** With a belongs_to for **User**

**Exercise** With a belongs_to for **User** && **Workout**

**Workout** with a belongs_to for **User**

Exercise would contain

```
weight
reps
distance
duration
```

So it would cover time-based distance elements like cycling or jogging as well as weights and reps

Letting you easily retrieve & create new data with

```
user.meals && user.meals.build
workout.exercises &&  workout.exercises.build
```

Comment: I don't understand the exercise part. Why would an exercise have weight/reps/distance/duration. An exercise is something like a "bench-press", or "running". So the recording model would have to belong to an exercise and a user. So you reckon it should be something like user.exercise_logs ? (A workout would be a collection of exercises).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the point of having a Log model if all you're doing is calculating attributes from other models. So I would set it up like so:

```
Class User
# t.integer  :weight  (or if this can change regularly make this an attribute of meal and     exercise so it's calculated and is logged specifically for those things)
has_many :meals
has_many :workouts
has_many :exercises, through: :workouts

class Meal
# t.integer :carbs
# t.integer :calories
# t.integer :fat   etc
belongs_to :user

class Workout
belongs_to :user
has_many :exercises

class Exercise
# t.integer :reps
# t.integer :duration
# t.integer :distance
# t.integer :barbell_weight  etc
belongs_to :workout
```

So then these models are essentially the logs, and if you want to log things like 'calorie burn based on user weight', etc, then you can just dynamically create "log" type spreadsheets based on the calculations. If you want to know such calculations for each meal/exercise, then I would make user weight an attribute of meal and either exercise/workout so that you always know how many calories were burned at a particular time in a user's year-long fitness regime.

EDIT based on comments:

```
class User
  has_many :logs

class Log
  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :user
```

if you also want to track meal logs in a similar way (as in, Meals are very different than the info being logged for them). then I'd do a polymorphic. But really, this is pretty specific to your situation, so you know your app the best and you need to make that decision.

Comment: But an exercise wouldn't have reps/duration/distance because an exercise is the name of an exercise, not the logs. A workout is a collection of exercises. What do you call the recording of an exercise?

Comment: So you're saying an object of Class Exercise could be "Running", and then a user could choose "Running" as part of Workout 1, and then record "5 miles" and "45 min", and then for Workout 2 choose "Running" and then record "3 miles" and "20 min"?

Comment: if that's the case, I would still not have a log model and just have an attribute of "Type" for Exercise, where you could have a select menu of different options like "Running", "Lifting", "Swimming", etc (and let the user add their own if they don't see what they want).

Comment: No... an exercise is for running/bench-press/deadlift/pull-ups. It's to designate the exercise being performed. That way you can view said exercise and see all the logs you've ever done for it. A workout is just a collection of exercises to be peformed...

Comment: yeah so if you want to see all the logs you've ever done for Exerice "pull-ups" then just search user.exercises.where(:type => "pull-ups"). If your Exercise model is only going to have the attribute "name" and many instances of :logs and nothing else, then that's just a longer, more database-expensive way of doing it that seems pretty circuitous imo.

Comment: But what if there's a global database of all exercises? E.g, a description of how to do it? Pictures? Videos? Not to mention wouldn't that create a lot of duplicated data? You'd perform sets for pull-ups many times a week for example. It could be part of more than one workout. So you'd want to see all your logs for that one exercise over time potentially.